# create UnicodeString with 1MB size having random characters

Tags: c++builder

For some application, I need to create String with 1MB having random characters.

One way maybe to get random characters by using System.Random API by looping for 1MB.

Are there any other APIs I can use to quickly get 1MB String?

Comment: you will have to create the random characters yourself in a loop

Comment: You could get ~1Mb of random data, base64 encode it, and get the first Mb of it as your string. It won't have all the possible characters but it should be random. The base64 is just to make sure you get readable characters, but some other kind of encoding could also work. You need to decide also if you want 1M of characters or 1Mb of data: remember that each character in UnicodeString will use 2 bytes.

Comment: @Wimmel Thank you for your reply. So I will do it by myself.

Comment: @RodrigoGómez Thank you for your reply. Base64 encoding is a good idea. I didn't know about that. I appreciate it.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to quickly fill a buffer with random data, but so far no luck, except what I guess you're going to do: a vector of the needed amount of ints (or doubles, or whatever), fill that in a loop, and then you can encode that block with base64 to get your string. Good luck.

Comment: @RodrigoGómez Thank you very much for your reply again. From your reply, I can see the steps I will do.

Comment: FYI, base64 increases the size of the encoded data by 4/3, so you would need 786432 bytes of input data (786432 `char`s, 393216 `word`s/`wchar_t`s, 196608 `int`s, 98304 `int64`s/`double`s, etc) to produce a 1MB base64 string.  Knowing those numbers might help you write smaller loops. You might also consider filling an even smaller buffer and then copy it multiple times to fill a larger buffer, which you can then base64 encode.  That will reduce the amount of random data you have to generate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much for your information. It helps for me to develop a function to produce the string.